# lset in Tcl using procedure and reference integer

Tags: tcl

I am trying to add values to a sublist using Tcl. Via the internet, I have found the most effective way to this is using `lset` as so:

```
lset x 0 end+1 $item
```

However, I having trouble with `lset` on a larger more complicated scale. The `lset` is inside of a procedure taking a reference variable from outside to refer to the correct spot on the list. I created simple test script to see if it would work:

```
set x { {} {} {} }
set refID 1
proc addValue {value} {
    global x refID
    set value [expr $value*2]
    lset x $refID end+1 $value 
} 
addValue 7
addValue 8
# => {} {14 16} {}
```

Works perfectly! However, when I go to my larger project, I keep getting 'list index out of range' although the list/sublist is set up the same.

```
set allNodes { {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} }
# Many lines of proc stuff
...
puts "Testing $currentHead $currentHeadID --- $n2 $nd2"
            if {$d<40 && $currentHeadID!=$nd2} {
                lappend members $nd2
                lset allNodes $currentHeadID end+1 $n2
               }
...
# continuing
```

I am able to get everything in the process to work and I know that the `currentHeadID` is an integer from the `puts`. How is the list index out of range? I have tried adjusting the `end` along with some other stuff, but cannot seem to figure it out.

Even when I add to my code a simple manual test:

```
set allNodes { {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} }

lset allNodes 0 end+1 5
# => list index out of range while executing
# "lset allNodes 0 end+1 5"
```

I still get the list index issue even though it is built the EXACT same way as my simple process. Is this a Tcl version issue? Does this have to do with running it through a simulator? What am I missing here?

Comment: if `$currentHeadId > [llength $allNodes]` then you'll get that error.

Comment: if `$currentHeadId == [llength $allNodes]` then you're essentially doing `lappend`

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, I understand that. ```$currentHeadID``` is always a random number between 0 and 19 therefore never greater than ```[llength $allNodes]``` which is 20. 99% of the time ```currentHeadID``` starts at 0, and it is does not pass testing as 0.

Comment: So what happens to allNodes in the "many lines of proc stuff" ? Does it get truncated somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a Tcl version issue?

Yes, it is. Tcl learnt extending lists via `[lset]` starting with Tcl 8.6 (see [TIP 331](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/331.md)), in Tcl 8.5 you will get `list index out of range`.

Comment: There's no chance of this functionality being backported to 8.5 either. We only backport changes that far very rarely, typically just enough to support our building and testing on supported platforms, and this feature isn't essential for that. Sounds like an honest `package require Tcl 8.6` at the top of the script is essential, and will at least make things fail fast and fail clearly in a way that deployers can stand a chance to figure out how to resolve.

Comment: Thank you guys. It definitely is a versioning issue. Using the ```package require Tcl 8.6``` I get ```version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.10, need 8.6```. However, I have 8.6 installed on my machine as I am able to run my simple program using ```tclsh test.tcl```. Is there a way I can apply 8.6 to be run by the simulator I am using? (NS2- network simulator 2)

Comment: You have to tell `ns` at build time to use Tcl 8.6: `./configure ... --with-tcl-ver=8.6 ...`. Check out https://www.min.at/prinz/?entry=entry181009-175821; in case of problems, this is worth a new SO question.